# Import SQLite to CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I'm totally noob in CoreData an I have a trouble. My test database incude 1 table named ZDOCTOR

```
CREATE TABLE "ZDOCTOR" (
 "id" integer NOT NULL ON CONFLICT REPLACE DEFAULT 0,
 "doctorName" text,
 "doctorSpec" text,
PRIMARY KEY("id")
)
```

App .xcdatamodel has 1 corresponding entity named "Doctor"[image]

There my setup managed context method:

```
- (void)setupManagedObjectContext
{
    _objectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    _objectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURL *appDocumentDir = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    NSString *documentsStorePath = [[appDocumentDir path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsStorePath]) {
        NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyApp" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        if (defaultStorePath) {
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:documentsStorePath error:NULL];
        }
    }
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:_objectModel];
    NSURL *defaultStoreURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsStorePath];
    [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:defaultStoreURL options:nil error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        abort();
    }
    [_objectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

In line `[coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:defaultStoreURL options:nil error:&error];` I got error `SQLite error code:1, 'table already exists'`.

But if I rename table to anything else, all ok, except that `[_fetchedResultContoller fetchedObjects]` is empty after `-performFetch:`

Comment: Was the sqlite file actually created with Core Data (and the same model)?

Comment: You're aware that Core Data **is not a SQLite wrapper**, right? Any more than Objective-C being an assembly language wrapper. You can't just open arbitrary SQLite files with Core Data, and Core Data makes no guarantees about how it will render its schemas down to tables or to statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're trying to create the SQLite table by hand instead of letting Core Data do so, and you're doing it wrong. Wrong in two senses: (1) your scheme is incorrect for Core Data (the table name is probably right, everything else is wrong), and (2) there actually is no right way because Core Data schemas are created using undocumented rules.

I'm not sure what your goal is here. This is not how Core Data is designed to be used. The fact that it uses SQLite is an implementation detail that is not reflected in Core Data's API (it can use non-SQLite stores too). If you're concerned about the actual schema then you're already doing Core Data wrong. You can of course use Core Data in a manner different from the one it was designed for, but if you do then you assume all of the trouble and risk of doing so.

As for the symptoms you describe, the error `table already exists` is quite clear. You created a table with the same name that Core Data wants to use but with a conflicting schema. Core Data is not reacting well to this.

The empty fetch requests after renaming the table make sense. Core Data's creating its own tables and (probably) ignoring the one you created.

If what you're trying to do is create a pre-populated data store, there are other SO questions that cover this. In general they involve creating the pre-populated store in Core Data, then saving that file to reuse later on.